# Skew left border of one side of an element in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to skew just the right side of a CSS element (specifically, forms and a submit button).

I found this Fiddle which works great for right sides.

http://jsfiddle.net/5a7rhh0L/3/

but I'm trying to do the same for just the left side.

This is the design I'm trying to get to

[Form design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY7ji.png)

I've tried this but it's skewing the entire field

```
.contactForm .elementor-field-textual {
   transform: skewX(-22deg);
-ms-transform: skewX(-22deg);
```

-webkit-transform: skewX(-22deg);
margin-left: 70px;

}

Comment: it will also skew your input field and text, and will also make the text blurry.. rather remove the skew and use ::before pseudo selector and rotate a little and placed it using position absolute.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'm going down the wrong road with this. From what I've read, I can't apply a pseudo element to a form field.

Answer (score 1):

Using the jsfiddle you linked you just have to change `transform-origin` and the position of your `:after`

```css
#a {
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    position: relative;
    

    color: #2E8DEF;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-left: none;
}
#a:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -1px;
    right: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
 <div id="a">
     Contact
    <br>Hello
    <br>Hi
</div>
<br>
 <div id="a">
     This
    <br>div
    <br>has
    <br>a
    <br>lot
    <br>of
    <br>rows
    <br>.
    <br>.
    <br>.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, but I don't think this is going to work with my form as I don;t think the pseudo elements will work with form/input field

Comment: You can embed your form in a div tag